Probability density distribution of waiting times at a traffic light
I'm trying to find the p.d.f. of x = time waited at a traffic light (if you're asking why, read below*).
Suppose the following:

the time of arrival at the traffic light is uniformly random

the cycle has G seconds of green light, and R seconds of red light;

T is the duration of the cycle, which starts with green at t0;

I arrive at the traffic light at t.


So the waiting time w is
/   0 if [t - t0 mod T] < G

w ={
\   T - [t - t0 mod T] otherwise
where mod is the modulo operator, t-t0 mod T is the time relative to the start of the cycle.
If I get there during the first G seconds of the cycle, my waiting time is 0; else, it is the remaining time in the cycle.
The cumulative probability function F(w) is, I think:
F(w) = G * H (w) + H(w) * H(R - w) * [t - t0 mod T]
where H is the Heaviside step function; since the p.d.f. is its derivative, and H is not differentiable, I have a hard time making sense of this (I could use the distributional derivative, but does it make sense to have a non-integrable p.d.f.?).
Can anyone point out any flaws or explain how this problem should be approached? I don't strictly want a p.d.f.: I just need a way to draw random waiting times according to a given traffic light cycle.
Thanks in advance!

Why this question? It looked like a fairly simple thing, but I found unexpected things and since I'm not an expert I want to find out if I made the right assumptions.


First we must consider some of your assumptions.
What kind of traffic intersection is this? Is it isolated (interactions with other intersection timing schedules is negligible), or is it part of a traffic network? The former is much easier to analyze, so let's use that as an assumption.
Are there any traffic detection mechanisms (loop detectors, cameras, etc.)? Easier to analyze if again we assume no, but many if not most intersections have some kind of detection mechanism.
What kind of traffic density is being analyzed? With light traffic we can assume exponential arrivals, but as traffic density increases arrivals become platooned. This mainly has an effect if detection mechanisms are present; if not we can ignore.
So going off these three assumptions, uniform arrival time is a good assumption. However, unless traffic is extremely light, even if you arrive during a green light there will be some waiting time associated with the queue buildup from the red light. If we further ignore this (and ignore acceleration and deceleration effects), we obtain the following.
Let $t=(T-T_0)\bmod C$ be the current cycle time, $T$ the current time, $T_0$ the master clock zero time, $C$ the cycle length, $G$ effective green time, and $R$ effective red time.
$$ w(t)=-(C-t)\mathbb I\{t\ge G\} $$
The distribution, as you note, can be written as
$$F_W(w) = \begin{cases} 0 & \text{if }\;w<0\\
\frac{G}{C} & \text{if }\;0\le w < G \\
\frac{w}{C} &\text{if }\;G\le w<C\\
1 & \text{if }\; w\ge C\end{cases}$$
Now you are right that the probability distribution for this function has a Heaviside function, but this function does have a derivative: the Dirac delta function $(\delta(w))$, which has zero width but infinite density, which upon integration yields a step function equal to the height of the Heaviside function. This is the case when we have a discrete distribution (or in this case a mixture of discrete and continuous). The density function can be written as follows.
$$ f_W(w)=\frac{G}{C}\delta(w=0)+\frac{R}{C}\mathbb I \{G\le w\le C\}$$
In order to make draws using a computer, I recommend using a mixture model. Whether a car arrives during a green light or a red light can be modeled using a Bernoulli distribution with $p=R/C$; if it arrives during a green light, set $w=0$; else use a uniform distribution with $W\sim \text{Unif}(0,R)$.

Thanks, I like your computational solution! I still have doubts about the pdf, since the Dirac function is the functional derivative; do functional derivatives still have meaning in this context?

I'll have to leave that question to the mathematics gurus on this site, but the use of this function for discrete probabilities was used by Papoulis & Pillai in their book Probability, Random Variables and Stochastic Processes. (Also by my professor using this book as reference.)

Also, here's some discussion from math.se: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1058447/generalised-probability-density-functions-using-dirac-deltas
